# Unload Assembly From App Domain

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Code should create domain, load dll into domain, unload dll

But dll is still there after calling unload on new domain?

```
 private void Method1()
 {
        //create new domain
        AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain");
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;

        //load dll into new domain
        AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName();
        assemblyName.CodeBase = "c:\\mycode.dll";
        Assembly assembly = domain.Load(assemblyName);         

        //do work with dll
        //...

        //unload dll
        AppDomain.Unload(domain); 

        //still showing dll below ?????
        Assembly[] aAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies(); 
}
static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    string[] tokens = args.Name.Split(",".ToCharArray());
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Resolving : " + args.Name);
    return Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(new string[] { "c:\\", tokens[0] + ".dll" }));
}
```

Any ideas why dll is not unloading?

EDIT (have got it to work as below)

As Jean pointed out domain.Load was the problem, using CreateInstanceAndUnwrap with a proxy class in same project works.)

instead of

```
    //load dll into new domain *** this does not work
    AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName();
    assemblyName.CodeBase = "c:\\mycode.dll";
    Assembly assembly = domain.Load(assemblyName);
```

to this

```
    // loads proxy class into new domain               
    Type myType = typeof(Proxy);
    var value = (Proxy)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
             myType.Assembly.FullName,
             myType.FullName);   
    //DoWork:- loads assembly into domain
    // calls methods, returns result                 
    Int32 result = value.DoWork(pathToDll);
    //Unload domain and thus assembly
    AppDomain.Unload(domain);
    //Assembly not present in current domain
    Assembly[] list = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

with below class added to current namespace

```
    public class Proxy : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public Int32 DoWork(string assemblyPath)
        {
            try
            {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
            Int32 response = 0;

            Type tObject = assembly.GetType("namespace.class");
            MethodInfo Method = tObject.GetMethod("method");

            Type myType = typeof(Proxy);
            object myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);                
            response =  (Int32) Method.Invoke(myInstance, null);

            return response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, as soon as you have an `Assembly` instance, it means that the assembly in question is loaded in the current domain.

Meaning that, when you call the [`AppDomain.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36az8x58.aspx) method, you load the assembly both in your current domain, and in the new domain. (As you can see in the remarks for that method on MSDN, "This method should be used only to load an assembly into the current application domain.")

**EDIT**: The previously posted "solution" was removed as it did not actually solve the issue. A working solution was edited into the question by the author.

Comment: No only in delegate method

Comment: @Dere_2929: What happens when you remove the `AssemblyResolve` hook? E.g., try to put the `AssemblyResolve` hook only on the `domain` instance.

Comment: your solution doesn't work but your first two paragraphs are correct and is the root of the problem. have posted solution in question edit, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't unload an `Assembly` from an `AppDomain` in .NET, Once an assembly is loaded into an `AppDomain` its there for the lifetime of the domain.

Comment: that is what I am trying to do (i.e AppDomain.Unload(domain)) but assembly is still loaded after this call

Comment: Well since its in you CurrentDomain you cant remove it untill the current domain is unloaded, somehow it has leaked from the child domain into you main domain

Answer (score 1):

```
//still showing dll below ?????
Assembly[] aAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

You're not checking `domain`, you're checking the current domain, which of course is still loaded.

You can't unload an assembly from an `AppDomain` without tearing down the whole domain.

Comment: im trying to load assembly into a seperate domain (not current), call a method from this assembly and then unload created app domain (which in effect unloads the assembly)